# Qt4 on which platforms?

Tags: qt, qt4, cross-platform, qt-creator, multiplatform

On which platforms is Qt4 available ? 
Where can I run Qt Creator ?

Thx.

Comment: "Qt supports the following platforms: 
Embedded Linux | Mac OS | Windows | Linux/X11 | Windows CE | Symbian | Maemo/MeeGo" http://qt.nokia.com/products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official versions of Qt are available for:

Windows
Linux
FreeBSD
MacOSX
Embedded Linux
Windows Mobile
Symbian
Maemo

---

Experimental:

Haiku
OpenSolaris
OS/2
Amiga OS4

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried visiting their own [website](http://qt.nokia.com/) ? If not, then you should.

About the execution issue, you can have their own IDE : [Qt Creator IDE](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/)

Answer (score 2):

["Qt supports the following platforms: Embedded Linux | Mac OS | Windows | Linux/X11 | Windows CE | Symbian | Maemo/MeeGo"](http://qt.nokia.com/products)